# Seamless animation loop for flags

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

I am working on flag which i am going to use in my game
I am stuck on the animation part. I can't get the animation to be seamless
I have seen many tutorials but i can't follow
I need a detailed tutorial on it with pictures (if possible)

P.S: Please keep in mind, i am new to Blender

Comment: how are you making the flag, are you using a cloth sim?

Comment: I used cloth modifier or whatever it is, I followed a tutorial
But it didn't taught how to make animation loop seamless

Comment: Thank you, Ray Mairlot but like i said "I am new to Blender"
I need a detailed tutorial or if you can share a link (video would be better) that would be great